# mysql trigger update field when other field updated

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table that stores my customers with a very simple structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipients` (
  `recipient_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(85) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `postal` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone_1` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone_2` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `anniversary` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipient_id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

what i'm looking for is to make mysql update the state field to 0 when the country field changes to some specific text. i.e if the country changes to UK i want the state field to automataclly be set to 'N/A'.

i know i can just go ahead and run an update statement but i wonder if mysql can do it so i won't have to worry about it.

Comment: So you know what you want and you know how to achieve that. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use triggers, see example below:

```
-- first you must change delimiter
DELIMITER $$

-- create the new trigger, if you want to update it then before create you must do
-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS your_name_here
CREATE TRIGGER your_name_here BEFORE UPDATE ON recipients FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- check if country now is UK
  IF NEW.country = 'UK' THEN
    -- if so, do your work
    SET NEW.state = 'N/A';
  END IF;

  -- you can put more code here as needed!
END $$

-- then reset delimiter
DELIMITER ;
```

see also the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: thanks Matteo. that should run for each update or i have to run this manually?